# Laravel 9. Проблема с маршрутом

Tags: laravel

У меня есть в welcome.blade.php форма `<form method="post" action="{{ route('form.send') }}" class="form">`. На локальном сервере она нормально работает, но на хостинге такое ощущение он не может найти этот маршрут, хотя в route:list он его видит

web.php
`Route::post('/', [PostController::class, 'send'])->name('form.send');`

При этом при нажатии на кнопку никаких ошибок не выходит, просто обновляется страницу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PostController.php

````
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request) {
        return "25";
    }
}```



Если заменить на action="#", то всё нормально.

php artisan route:clear пробовал, ничего не вышло.

при php artisan route:cache выдаёт ошибку The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD, POST.
````

Comment: А если чутка изменить роут типа Route::post('/send', [PostController::class, 'send'])->name('form.send'); Выглядит все правильно, может все таки отличаются файлы на сервере и на локали...

Comment: Так сработало, но хотелось бы чтобы никуда не перекидывало

Comment: Если что можно в методе send() после выполнения кода написать return back(); 
А можно полный код web.php может у вас там конфликт какой роутов...

Comment: `<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');

Route::post('/', [PostController::class, 'send'])->name('form.send');`

Comment: Может сам роут как-то по другому назвать, чтоб  без точки было?

Comment: А всё я понял!! у вас для одного роута '/' два наименования - home и form.send Так нельзя

Comment: Очень странно, но он просто обновляет страницу. А если как предлагали маршрут заменить на /send, то он работает

Comment: Вы мой коммент выше прочитали?

Comment: Да, оставил name только для одного маршрута, тоже самое.

Comment: а команда php artisan route:cache выполняется?

Comment: она выполняется, только потом страница перестаёт работать и выдаёт ошибку The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD, POST.